# Woocommerce cart calculate fees issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have create hook action

```
  do_action('wpyoug_update_price');

  add_action('wpyoug_update_price', 'wpyoug_update_woocommerce_price');
  function wpyoug_update_woocommerce_price(){
     global $totalshipCharge;
     add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'cp_add_custom_price' );    
  }
```

When I echo inside wpyoug_update_woocommerce_price() function it return . but  add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'cp_add_custom_price' ); is not working

```
 function cp_add_custom_price(){
     global $woocommerce;
     $thiscarttotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
     $thiscarttotal = preg_replace('/$/', '', $thiscarttotal);
      $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Miscellaneous Handling Fee', 'woocommerce'), 10 );
      }
```

Comment: do you want this cp_add_custom_price function in any particular page

Comment: Yes I want to update price

Comment: just add page conditions on the function because the way you are using it right.

Comment: Can you please put code. What you want to say

Comment: @Sudhir You cart fee adding function is not correct, please try with below answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// Hook before adding fees 
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');

function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    $fees = 0.08;
    $cart->add_fee( 'Handling fee', $fees);
}
```

Comment: I have put same code. But it not working. I am using this code inside shortcode. Is it is reason for not working?

Comment: you just add if condition with your post data inside this function

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','xa_add_surcharge' );
function xa_add_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $surcharge = 5; 
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

}
```

[From here](https://www.xadapter.com/woocommerce-code-snippet-adding-surcharge-cart-checkout/)

Comment: @David I have put exactly same code. But it is not returning anything.

Comment: I have put this code inside shortcode. Is it is reason behind it

Comment: @Sudhir Simply putting this code in active child theme's  functions.php will add surcharge

Comment: @Sudhir You cannot use that inside shortcode. Just put it in active theme's functions.php and try

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But I want to run it on some condition after form POST method. So How can I use it?

Comment: Can I perform this using Ajax

Comment: @Sudhir surcharge will be added to cart whenever "woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees" this hook getting called. You can trigger that in your Ajax